# Unexpected EOF and a function looping endlessly?

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding a site with replit.com and have come across a problem that I don’t understand, as I am very new to using JavaScript. I get an unexpected EOF error and another error saying "maximum call stack size exceeded":

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
onload@/:9:7
    at /:9:7
```

This is the JavaScript that causes the problem, with the onload() function being the one that seems to loop when used with onload on a body element in HTML:

```
function onload() {
  mobile = 0;
  laptopPC = 0;
  console = 0;
}


function mobileScreenshotCategories() {
  if (mobile == 0) {
    document.getElementById("FalloutShelter").innerHTML = "Fallout Shelter";
    mobile = 1;
  } else if (mobile == 1) {
    document.getElementById("FalloutShelter").innerHTML = "";
    mobile = 0;
  };
}


function laptopPCScreenshotCategories() {
  if (laptopPC == 0) {
    document.getElementById("GenshinImpact").innerHTML = "Genshin Impact";
    laptopPC = 1;
  } else if (laptopPC == 1) {
    document.getElementById("GenshinImpact").innerHTML = "";
    laptopPC = 0;
  };
}


function consoleScreenshotCategories() {
  if (console == 0) {
    document.getElementById("Borderlands3").innerHTML = "Borderlands 3;
    console = 1;
  } else if (console == 1) {
    document.getElementById("Borderlands3").innerHTML = "";
    console = 0;
  };
}
```

The problem began after editing the consoleScreenshotCategories() function.

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do with the problem, but the symbol `console` should be left for the browser's console (as in `console.log("something")`. Try using another name for that variable?

Comment: I think since console is in a function it can tell the difference, same with the word new I believe.

Comment: What do you mean? How can you do e.g. `console.log("hello");` after `console = 0;` inside `onload()`?

Comment: I thought it would do nothing if it did not have the '.' and then the rest of the text after it? I also thought you were talking about the function sorry.